# C# call function of object inside lambda and orderby

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to call a method of an object inside a lambda expression and then order the list. Is it possible to do this in one expression?

this is what i have right now, it works:

```
// FindItemsResults<Item> is of namespace Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FindItemsResults<Item>
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
        WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, 
        view
    );


foreach (Item myItem in findResults.Items.Where(o => LoadObject(o) == true).OrderByDescending(o => o.DateTimeCreated))
{
 // Do that stuff again...
}            


private static bool LoadObject(Item o)
{
    o.Load();
    return true;
}
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to do this without the call to LoadObject, being able to do the o.Load inside the lambda expression. It's a Void method, so validating it against a Boolean is not going to work.

Thanks for all your input.

Kind regards.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this. LINQ is intended for querying data, and it shouldn't have side effects. I suggest you load the items via a normal loop and then do your querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

For example, you can create the extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Item> Load(this IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            item.Load()

            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

and then call it like:

```
foreach (var item in findResults.Items.Load().OrderByDescending(o => o.DateTimeCreated))
{
    // Do some stuff...
}
```

But I would say that you can call `Load` method right inside your loop.

Comment: Ofcourse an extension method would do the trick, thanks for that!
I could call the item.Load inside the loop, but then I wouldn't be able to order by DateTime cause that fields requires to be loaded.

Comment: I see. Then extension method will do what you need. Or you need to go through your items at first and call `load`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit awkward that Exchange provides the Item results as unloaded results. Don't know why that is. the extension method is implemented now and works like a charm! Thanks @MaKCbIMKo

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` extension method expects a delegate that returns a Boolean value.  You cannot supply a VOID.  Yacoub Massad was correct in his comment that a LINQ query expression should not have side effects on the underlying data.  If you want to remove the foreach loop because you believe it creates cleaner code, then you can use `List(of T).ForEach` to perform an action on each item, and then on the next line query and order your items.  For example:

```
findResults.Items.ToList().ForEach(o => o.Load(o));

foreach (var item in FindResults.Items.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateTimeCreated))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not always considered good practice from a pure functional programming point of view, but I define the follow two extension methods:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(
   this IEnumerable<T> pEnumerable,
   Action<T> pAction
) {
   foreach (var item in pEnumerable)
      pAction(item);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> ForEachWithContinue<T>(
   this IEnumerable<T> pEnumerable,
   Action<T> pAction
) {
   pEnumerable.ForEach(pAction);
   return pEnumerable;
}
```

And then you can do the following:

```
findResults
.Items
.ForEachWithContinue(o => o.Load())
.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateTimeCreated)
.ForEach(o => {
   // do more stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, somehow i missed it while answering in the comments of MaKCbIMKo